# Using underscore variables in python when building graphs

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, graph

What is the advantage of using underscore variables when building graphs when I can get the same result by just constructing graphs without an assignment?

I am doing a datacamp course where the use of underscores variables was recommended when building graphs.
I can't find the exact part where the instructor reasoned about this.

```
# Plot the histogram
_ = plt.hist(versicolor_petal_length, bins=n_bins)

# Label axes
_ = plt.xlabel('petal length (cm)')
_ = plt.ylabel('count')

# Show histogram
plt.show()
```

Alternatively I get the same output with this:

```
# Plot the histogram
plt.hist(versicolor_petal_length, bins=n_bins)

# Label axes
plt.xlabel('petal length (cm)')
plt.ylabel('count')

# Show histogram
plt.show()
```

Could someone explain the advantage of assigning underscore variables in this particular case and in general?

Comment: I personnally would not recommend using those assignments; so it's definitely also a question of taste. Just note that it *sometimes* makes sense to assign the return to a variable when using interactive sessions and not wanting to have the interpreter print out the returned values.

Comment: The usual use for assignments to `_` is to discard unneeded elements when unpacking a sequence: `first, _, third = returnThreeThings()` for example.  There *are* some cases where you do need to keep a reference to something even though you will not further use it yourself (matplotlib animations, for one), but you'd want to use distinct names or you'd only be able to keep a singe reference alive.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that would be my assumption here, preventing printing in a REPL

Comment: Ok I see it is a matter of taste. In this case the only reason is to have a "clean" interpreter print out although I don't see how this is a big issue. Thanks